# Create cspkg and cscfg from Linux Windows Azure SDK for a PHP Project

Tags: php, linux, azure, cloud

I'm a PHP Developer and i need to deploy my new project to a Windows Azure Cloud. I develop on linux and after searching on the internet i couldn't find a solution for my problem:
I need to create cspkg and cscfg  files to upload configurations and packages for my app.

How can i do it ? Is there some command for linux console that create these files ?

Sorry for my bad english but i'm Italian and i'm writing by night!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/common-tasks/create-web-and-worker-roles/? Some more links for PHP can be found here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/cloud-services/.

I mostly develop on Windows (so I may be wrong) but if I'm not mistaken, you would need to download Windows Azure SDK for PHP for Linux from here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/?sdk=php. This one should have some templates for building cloud services using PHP. You may also want to explore CLI tools for Linux which you can also download from the download link above.

Comment: Thanks! Now i'm looking to generate a pfx or cer certificate for deploy my projects. I need to do it also on linux !

Comment: Again being a novice on Linux, see if `KeyTool`/`KeyStore` thing is there? Some days back I wrote a blog post on Java and Service Management API and I created a certificate using that (but on Windows Machine): http://gauravmantri.com/2013/08/25/consuming-windows-azure-service-management-api-in-java/